# Within an "update" git hook, can I cd to a clone, `git fetch`, then `git checkout` the new commit?

Tags: git, hook, githooks

In an "update" git hook, I'm trying to cd to a clone of the repo, run `git fetch`, and `git checkout` the new commit. But I don't think that commit exists yet. Is there any way to accomplish this? I tried doing `git archive [sha]` but it takes too long, considering how often this hook will run in our company.

Should I checkout the base reference of the update, then apply a generated patch or something?

Comment: The `update` [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is very similar to `pre-receive`, meaning the commit isn't there yet.  Try using `post-receive`?

Comment: @mattalxndr - Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Sam I need to be able to refuse the commit

Comment: @BroiSatse I want to run code mess tests before accepting a push into the codebase.

Comment: @mattalxndr - I think it would be a better idea to have your bare repo hidden from your developers and point their repos into a new proxy-like dev repo. Then, on update hook you can just run tests and push if everything is all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with something like this:

```
git diff [OLD-COMMIT] [NEW-COMMIT] > /tmp/update.patch
cd /path/to/the/existing/clone
git fetch origin
git reset --hard [OLD-COMMIT]
git apply /tmp/update.patch
# Run tests
```

Works great.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of for your use case is to have 2 git repos. A workflow would go something like this.

```
git commit
git push ServerA
# post-receive checks out commit and runs unit tests
# ERROR: message returned
# fix your code
git commit
git push ServerA
# post-receive checks out commit and runs unit tests
# SUCCESS: pushes to ServerB
```

Since you want to reference a commit (which requires `post-receive`) **and** be able to reject a commit (which requires `pre-receive`), don't know if there is any better way.  I will say that normal workflow is to run some tests locally, and then push to the repo to run complete tests.  If it fails, push a fixed commit, and then when you merge everything into your develop/master branch you can rebase all the extra commits.

Comment: Actually, in both pre-receive and update hooks, the new objects *are* in the repo, it's just that the references are not yet updated.  So you can actually extract things; you have to use the "proposed update" SHA-1s directly though.

Comment: @torek interesting, even if OP were to `mkdir /tmp/repo; cd /tmp/repo; git init; git remote add origin [...]; git fetch origin; git checkout [proposed update]` or does it only work in the current repo (where `pre-receive`/`update` was fired from)?  Do you have any link to that so I can put together something for OP?

Comment: Unfortunately `fetch` won't get them because they're not referenced yet, so yes, only current repo.  The hook can `git --work-tree=... checkout` by SHA-1 (you might want to set up a separate index file too).  I have not actually tried any of this; this idea is just based on how git works internally.